# Is there a way for Perl to report on the exact line number for Error

Tags: perl

Here is the code that will produce error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict
use warnings FATAL=>'all';

use ExtUtils::Installed;

my $instmod = ExtUtils::Installed->new();

foreach my $module ($instmod->modules())
{
    my $version = $instmod->version($module) || "???";
    print "$module -- $version\n";
    }
```

Just dont use ";" in use strict

error:

```
syntax error at ListModules.pl line 3, near "use strict
use warnings "
Execution of ListModules.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Perl Version info:

```
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Comment: The error _is_ on line three. The second `use` is invalid without the `;`, but the `;` doesn't have to be on line 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, **no**. But it's not quite that simple.

There is a difference between a syntax error and a human error. Your human error was to omit the `;` at the end of line 2, but this resulted in a syntactical error on line 3. There is no way for your computer to know that you meant to write a `;` on line 2, and it would be counter-productive for it to try to guess.

It's only with the benefit of hindsight — you have the memory of your intentions — that you can see a differential between the error output and what you spot with your eyes.

In conclusion, the output *is* correct; it's just reporting something subtly different from what you're looking for... and what you are looking for is intractible. Learning to read error messages and translate them into the knowledge you need to spot the human error is an invaluable programmer's skill, and it comes naturally with practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error on line 2. You could have written

```
use strict
   'vars';
```

and the problem can be fixed by changing what you wrote to

```
use strict
;use warnings;
```

The syntax error is the `use` in the middle of an expression, and that happens on line 3.